# How to count rows in MYSQL table with multiple column criteria?

Tags: mysql

I have a table to football results in a mysql table and want to count how many games have been played by season and game type.

For example the table looks like this

```
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Type        |  Season     |   Goals  |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Club        |    11       |    4     |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|International  |    12       |    5     |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
|   Club        |    12       |     0    |
+---------------+-------------+----------+
```

What I want to do is total the number of club games played in season 12 so that would result in 1.

the current MYSQL code I have is

```
"SELECT COUNT * FROM table WHERE season='12' AND type='club'"
```

and that isn't working as I think I am using the wrong function. What is the correct function for the desired output?

Comment: What should be your output?

Comment: Hello Aasim, are the results incorrect or you get an error?
If you are getting an error you should use "COUNT(*)" instead of "COUNT *".

If you do not get an error, can you specify what data you get with the above SQL statement?

Comment: I get a syntax error for both * and (*)

Comment: you are running this in php or in database ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM `<tablename>` WHERE season=12 AND type='club';
```

make sure your connection established:

```
 $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM cristiano WHERE season=12 AND which='club'"
 if ($result=mysql_query($sql)) {
    while($row=mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
     echo $row['total'];
    }
 } else {
   echo "Error" . mysql_error();
   }
```

Comment: you need to provide your table name whatever it is ok

Comment: try again and let me know if error comes again ,, also remove quotes around season number

Comment: its not returning any errors now but how would I echo the result? For a SUM function I hade $goals = $row['sum']; and then would echo $goal in a div.

Comment: $q = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `cristiano` WHERE season=12 AND which='club';") or die(mysql_error());
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$games = $row['count'];

Answer (score 0):

I think you use the count() function it will work.Please find the below query
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE season='12' AND type='club';

Answer (score 0):

here Table name is 'table' and type-column name is 'type' - 
These both words 'table' and 'type' are reserved words, so while executing the query , write the query as:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `table` WHERE `season`=12 AND `type`='club';
```

use ` sign as used in above code-line.